# How to update all where in

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, entity-framework-6

Here are some of my tables in database

> User(**UserEmail**, ...)
>  Cake(**CakeId**, Name, Stock, ...)
>   Cart(***UserEmail***, ***CakeId***, ...)

How to make a lambda expression to match the SQL query:

```
UPDATE Cake 
SET Stock = Stock - 1
WHERE CakeId IN (SELECT CakeId FROM Cart WHERE UserEmail = "someone@example.com")
```

in Entity Framework?

Basically, I'd like to reduce all cake stock by 1 which exists in currently logged in user's cart.

Comment: You could e.g. let EF directly run your SQL. Or you could e.g. use [Linqer](http://www.sqltolinq.com/) to generate EF code from your SQL query.

Comment: Lambdas are for querying. If you want to do a batch update, use raw SQL. EF (and all ORMs) deal with individual objects. They are unsuitable for batch operations. You'd have to load all objects, update each one then save all changes back to the database. That's not an EF limitation, that a problem for all ORMs

Comment: You don't need the subquery either, use a `FROM Cake inner join Cart on Cake.CakeID=Cart.CakeID WHERE UserEmail =...'`

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
   var cakes = (from c in dataContext.Cakes
    join ca in dataContext.Carts on c.cakeId equals ca.cakeId
    where ca.UserEmail = "someone@example.com"
    select c);

    foreach(Cake c in cakes)
    {
       c.Stock--;
    }
```

Comment: That won't update anything unless you save the changes. It's also the most inefficient way to do an update - loading all objects in memory just to update a single value, then send everything back down. A simpe `UPDATE MyTable SET Stock=Stock-1` would be a *lot* faster

Comment: Using joins with ORMs is a *very* strong smell. It means the relations between the entities are missing. A `Cake` should have a `Cart` property, which would allow you to write `where cake.Cart.UserEmail =...`. LINQ isn't a replacement for SQL

Answer (score 0):

You can get the stock, and update it using foreach loop,

```
//begin transaction
var context = DBcontext.Database.BeginTransaction();
//Select cakes that contains useremail "" in their carts 
var cakes = DBcontext.Cakes.where(c => c.Carts.Any(x => x.UserEmail == "someone@example.com"));
// Loop through
foreach (var cake in cakes)
{
cake.Stock--;
//then update context 
DBcontext.Entry(cake).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
//Then save changes 
DBcontext.SaveChanges();
//then commit the transaction
context.commit();
```

Comment: This doesn't perform a batch update, it loads all objects in memory, updates one property, then writes everything back out. That's N different update statements. You don't need the transaction either, SaveChanges uses its own transaction

Comment: `Cakes` is already a Queryable. This isn't Queryable vs Enumerable. This code loads all relevant objects, modifies them then writes them back. An UPDATE statement though would just modify the relevant fields directly without loading anything. This is a fundamental limitation of all ORMs. For N rows, you have one big load and N individual updates

Comment: Now I understand 
sorry my bad, I didn't know that what you are looking for, i am not sure if it is possible with entity framework, 
I will be waiting for answers with you then :)

Comment: I'm not the OP. I'm saying that *this* is a bad idea and a very common bug. EF allows you to execute a raw SQL statement anyway

Comment: You might have heard about the N+1 problem ? That's a similar case

Comment: I thought I can help you, then it turns you taught me something, thank you. I use this everywhere, even the architect didn't mention that it is bad.

Comment: I asked, and someone told me there is one library called [z Entity Framework](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus)

Check it, it has some limitation but can be used 
See [here](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus/wiki/EF-Batch-Update-%7C-Entity-Framework-Batch-Update-Objects-Without-Loading-Them)

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Plus](http://entityframework-plus.net/)

This library have a Batch Update features which are what you are looking for

Here is an example how to use it.

```
ctx.Cake.Where(x => x.UserEmail = "someone@example.com")
        .Update(x => new Cake() { Stock = x.Stock - 1 });
```

All rows will be updated without loading entities in the memory.

Wiki: [EF+ Batch Update](http://entityframework-plus.net/batch-update)